# GRUB menu doesn't show Windows 10 in dual boot with Ubuntu (on separate drives)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I've searched around and not found anything quite like the issue I'm having.

I have Windows 10 on an NVME drive and I want to install Ubuntu to a second SSD on the same system.

I tried earlier and went through the basic install and it seemed successful - the machine booted to Ubuntu.

I was expecting the GRUB menu screen and I didn't get it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Should I install ubuntu manually?

If I set a timer to -1 on in `/etc/default/grub` then the GRUB menu will show up but still Windows 10 is not listed.

If I hit <kbd>esc</kbd> on launch I get a `grub>` command interface, and by typing `exit` I get into Windows.

I should note that my main display is 1440 and the Ubuntu install defaults to my 1080 display. Could that be an issue? Can't think it would be since GRUB doesn't care.

How can I get the GRUB menu to appear on boot with options for Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode? Your boot into Windows seems like a reboot into UEFI. And when both are not UEFI or both BIOS, you can only dual boot from UEFI boot menu. Post link to Summary Report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Windows 10 is installed in UEFI mode. I have fast boot disabled. I created a live usb with ubuntu but i cannot set it to UEFI mode.?

Answer (score 0):

- **Check if the `Fast Startup` option is disabled in `Windows`,** if it is
  disabled you can skip this step !

  1. Open `Control Panel`
  2. Scroll through `Power options`
  3. Select `Choose what the power buttons do`
  4. Click on `Change settings that are currently unavailable`
  5. Under `Shutdown settings`, uncheck `Turn on fast startup` & Save changes
  6. Shutdown Windows
- **Disable `Secure Boot` & `Fast Startup` , under `BIOS settings`**
- **Check Boot Priorities, set `Ubuntu` as first priority in Boot Priorities**
- **Save Changes & Exit `BIOS settings`.**
- **Hope this solved your problems,** if not post the errors you encountered (Hopefully None) **(*_^)**

Comment: I did  this previous didn't solve my issue. Still cant see windows in GRUB menu.

Comment: Did you tried GRUB update option ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved 
Did not have much data on windows drive so reformatted and installed to UEFI then later installed Ubuntu on second drive.

Windows is now in GRUB

Thanks.